# Write new file with digit before extension

Tags: python

I have a several files in a directory with the the following names

```
example1.txt
example2.txt
...
example10.txt
```

and a bunch of other files.

I'm trying to write a script that can get all the files with a file name like `<name><digit>.txt` and then get the one with higher digit (in this case **example10.txt**) and then write a new file where we add +1 to the digit, that is **example11.txt**

Right now I'm stuck at the part of selecting the files .txt and getting the last one.

Here is the code

```
import glob
from natsort import natsorted

files = natsorted(glob.glob('*[0-9].txt'))
last_file = files[-1]
print(files)
print(last_file)
```

Comment: At a glance, this code looks like it should work. What's the problem exactly? Please include the output in the question. You can [edit]. If you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: You can use a regexp to get the integer at the end of the filename. Increment that and use it for the new file.

Comment: @wjandrea The code never even tries to increment the integer, how can you say it works?

Comment: @Barmar OP's saying they're stuck on getting the last file, but this code looks like it should do that. This is the step before extracting the number and incrementing it.

Comment: Oh, missed that detail

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script in the directory containing the files?

Comment: @Barmar Oh actually, maybe I misunderstood the question. cbornes, are you saying this code is not working, or it is working but you don't know where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to split the file name in the text and number part, increment the number and join everything else together to have your new file name:

```py
import re
import glob
from natsort import natsorted

files = natsorted(glob.glob('*[0-9].txt'))
last_file = files[-1]

base_name, digits = re.match(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)\.txt', last_file).groups()
next_number = int(digits) + 1
next_file_name = f'{base_name}{next_number}.txt'

print(files)
print(last_file)
print(next_file_name)
```

Note that the regex assumes that the base name of the file has only alpha characters, with no spaces or `_`, etc. The regex can be extended if needed.

Comment: That works quite well thanks. Now that I see the solution looks quite obvious. But well I guess that's part of being a noob trying to learn python on its own.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script, it will work well for your purpose i think.

```
import os

def get_last_file():
    files = os.listdir('./files')
    
    for index, file in enumerate(files):
        filename = str(file)[0:str(file).find('.')]
        digit = int(''.join([char for char in filename if char.isdigit()]))
        files[index] = digit
    files.sort()
    return files[-1]

def add_file(file_name, extension):
    last_digit = get_last_file() +1
    with open('./files/' + file_name + str(last_digit) + '.' + extension, 'w') as f:
        f.write('0')

# call this to create a new incremental file.
add_file('example', 'txt')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple solution.

```py
files = ["example1.txt", "example2.txt", "example3.txt", "example10.txt"]
highestFileNumber = max(int(file[7:-4]) for file in files)
fileToBeCreated = f"example{highestFileNumber+1}.txt"
print(fileToBeCreated)
```

output:

```
example11.txt
```

.txt and example are constants, so theres no sense in looking for patterns. just trim the example and .txt

Comment: `<name>` is not a set string, based on the question